# ¿Cómo puedo trabajar con subconjuntos de columnas no necesariamente contiguas de un Dataframe de Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un DataFrame que consta de las siguientes columnas:

- Fecha y hora
- Temperatura del motor 1
- Par del motor 1
- Temperatura del motor 2
- Par del motor 2
- Temperatura del motor 3
- Par del motor 3
- Temperatura ambiente
- Temperatura del equipo
- Velocidad de avance de una cinta

  Necesitaría crear grupos de datos con la las variables específicas de cada motor y las generales del equipo. Por ejemplo:
- Temperatura del motor 1
- Par del motor 1
- Temperatura ambiente
- Temperatura del equipo
- Velocidad de avance de una cinta

  Mi idea sería calcular primero las diferencias de temperatura de cada motor respecto de la temperatura ambiente e intentar modelizar estas diferencias en función del par de la máquina correspondiente, de la temperatura del equipo y de la velocidad de avance de la cinta.

---

Comment: Estás usando pandas?

Comment: Sí, estoy usando Pandas. He probado con la orden groupby pero me da error.

Comment: Podés encontrar una muy buena respuesta (en inglés) acá: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Gracias, sí ha funcionado